# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotDisplayedError Happening ONLY for I.E. automated tests

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

Hi I'm testing an application using the Selenium::Webdriver API.

I have an issue that only appears to be effection IE 7/8 which run 
fine on Chrome and Firefox.

When I try to click on a menu link in IE I get the 
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotDisplayedError) error.

This issue is only present in IE8 but must be resolved as the business 
only supports IE8, officially, so my automated tests must work under 
that browser.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Loga

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with today's release (version 2.1.0)?

From the [blog](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/):

> There are also some bug fixes in the Firefox and IE WebDrivers, particularly when dealing with elements that are *just* off screen

The fact that it is a display error means it could be related

Comment: The test suite doesn't even run, when I upgrade to 2.1.0. I get the error: "RubyGem version error: selenium-webdriver(2.1.0 not ~> 0.2.0)"